# Genetic vs hereditary

Tags: word-usage

It's common for people to use the word "genetic" when referring to traits that are inherited, for example eye colour, near-sightedness etc

Is that usage necessarily incorrect though, as it relates to genes themselves ? Is "hereditary" a more correct choice ?

*Example:*

Everyone in my family wears glasses, it's ___

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you could use either *genetic* or *hereditary*. (Although you should correct the comma splice...)

But these words are not technically interchangeable across the board. Further details can be found on this very good blog article, "[The difference between genetic and hereditary](https://evolutionarybio.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/the-difference-between-genetic-and-hereditary/)".

Comment: See also, "Sporadic vs. Hereditary Cancer". [ http://www.siuh.edu/Our-Services/Clinical-Services/Cancer-Services/The-Hereditary-Cancer-Genetics-Program/Sporadic-vs-Hereditary-Cancer.aspx ]

Comment: Hi, Tim. Linking just a website is not encouraged in this community as your link can become invalid if the linked page changes. Why not copy and past essential parts of the link? Thanks.

Comment: I considered doing that, but decided against it in this circumstance for 2 reasons: 1) I do not believe I should copy this author's content directly from his page without his consent, and I didn't have time to bother with that; 2) If I copied it here, and the author chose to change something in his original text, this copy would potentially reflect out of date material. Since this is a somewhat scientific article, I didn't want to cross that line.

Comment: Just because something is posted on the internet doesn't mean its not copyright. However quoting short extracts of an article is almost always allowed as 'fair use'.

Comment: @Rathony, please feel free to ask Meta... Again, under the circumstances, it would have taken quoting fairly large chunks of the blog in order to explain the differences. This seemed like the shortest route; and as well, a simple Internet search would provide numerous resources to distinguish between genetics and inherited traits. ;)